# Find 4 numbers i arithmetic progression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Four integers in A.P their sum is 24 and their product is 945 .Find them
I assumed them as
$$a-d,a,a+d,a+2d$$
From the givens we get 
$$4a+2d=24$$
then
$$2a+d=12$$
Then apply the product to get 4th degree equation 
my question is there a simpler way to avoid the the 4th degree equation?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid this easy equation $(a-9)(a-3)(a^2-12a-315)=0$?

Answer (score 1):

we have the equations $$4a+6d=24$$ and $$a(a+d)(a+2d)(a+3d)=945$$
from the first equation we get
$$d=4-\frac{2}{3}a$$ plugging this in the second equation and factorizing:$$(a-3)(a-9)(a^2-12a-315)=0$$
you will have to solve the equation
$$a^4+24a^3-144a^2+3456a-8505=0$$
often is it useful to make the ansatz
$$a^4+24a^3-144a^2+3456a-8505=(x^2+Ax+B)(x^2+Cx+D)$$

Comment: Iam asking for a way to avoid this equation @Dr.sonnhard Graubner

Answer (score 1):

Note that the product of integers $$a-d,a,a+d,a+2d$$ should be 945.

Upon factorization of $$945 = 3\times 5\times 7\times 9$$ we find out that our terms are $$ 3,5,7,9$$

That is $a=5$ and $d=2$

Comment: Iam asking for a way to avoid this equation ? @Mohammad Riazi-Kermani